# MySQL group_concat and nest with another group_concat

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-concat

Not sure if the title explains the situation right but I will try to do my best explaining here.

I have a table with 3 fields linked to other tables and I want to get all the Rows grouped in the following way:

```
item_id, user_id, group_id
   1        2         3
   2        2         3
   3        4         5
   4        2         4
```

In my query i want in comma separated format all the items_id grouped by group_id i also have some extra conditions on the WHERE clause that's why the inner join

That i can do like with this query

```
 "SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT A.item_id ) AS ids
    FROM tableA A
    INNER JOIN tableB B ON(tableA.id = tableB.id)
   WHERE xxxxx
  GROUP BY A.group_id

 "
```

Later i can loop the results and using the comma separated to inner loop every id within the result

But i also want to group it by user_id in order to do something like this

```
foreach( query_results.... ){
      foreach( group_id.... ){
           foreach( item_id.... ){
                 // Display info
           }
      }
 }
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: If you're using PHP, then I can't really see why you'd use GROUP_CONCAT at all!

Comment: @Strawberry what do you mean?

Comment: Well, why not just return an ordered array and let PHP loop over that? To my mind, unless you're using it in conjunction with some other aggregating function, there is no problem in SQL for which GROUP_CONCAT is the solution - especially where PHP is concerned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use 2 GROUP_CONCATS**

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT A.item_id ) AS ids, 
        GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT A.group_id ) AS groups

     FROM tableA A
     INNER JOIN tableB B ON(tableA.id = tableB.id)
     WHERE xxxxx
     GROUP BY A.group_id
```

Loop your resource then use [Explode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) on the `groups` and `ids` value and loop them both as you want

Comment: @Strawberry Feel free to post a better idea as an answer, better implementation = better code

Answer (score 1):

using subqueries, we can get both itemids, userids as two seperate columns

```
select T1.group_id, T1.itemids, T2.userids

FROM 
(SELECT group_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT A.item_id ) AS itemids
    FROM table1 A
group by group_id) T1
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT 
    group_id, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT A.user_id ) AS userids
    FROM table1 A
group by group_id
  ) T2
on T1.group_id = T2.group_id
```